# Core Data - Shared model with target specifications?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a project with many targets representing a variation of our different Apps.
All targets share 90% of the Core Data Model and have a small amount of unique entities that relevant specifically for each target.

I am looking for ideas how to handle a shared model with specifications.
I could think of few options -

1. Create a different Model for each (Which we wish to avoid)
2. Create 1 Model for the shared entities and one for each target (But as I understand We will have issues with relationships)
3. Create 1 Model with abstract parent entities and child entities for the different usage of every app.

I am looking for more ideas or recommendation from someone that already faced this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. The two-model approach have a big problem with a migration. When you have a two models in the your app the lightweight migration is not works (the coredata bug). I have a several suggestions: 1) The one big shared model plus the each app has a some additional entities inside shared model with an own naming 2) Inside of the `.xccoredata` file is contains the `xml`.. can write a script which will merge a shared model with the additional model before a phase of compile. 3) If amount of additional entities is not big you can implement that via `nsuserdefaults` + own wrappers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use one model but with different configuration names for different apps.

In the Core Data model editor you can create multiple configurations. A configuration is just a named subset of the model, which contains some but not necessarily all of the entities in the data model.

When your app sets up its Core Data stack, the call to `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` has that second argument, `configuration`. Pass in one of the configuration names from your data model, and you get only that subset of the model.

Comment: Looks great, does auto migration apply to the configuration as the default configuration (Adding and removing entities in the future) ?, Thanks

Comment: The rules don't change-- what matters is how the model used for the existing data file compares to the new version of the model. If [lightweight migration can handle those differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1), you're all set.